# MySQL connector reference in asp.net applications

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-services

I had two applications that was able to run on my local machine in asp.net through visual studio. A webservice and a web forms app. I decided to try and deploy the webservice to my web host online, but it didnt work, so i tried to remove the reference i had to the MySql data connector and then move it to the "bin" folder and re-reference it. This resulted in that my local application broke, and when i tried to undo what i had done, it just remained with the same error. I have tried to uninstall and install various versions of the MySql connector, but without luck. The reference to the MySql connector also got broken in the web forms app, which i didnt delete the reference in, so now neither of them runs.

"Adgang nægtet" means "Access denied".

Here is the error for the webservice
http://pastebin.com/81wuP68j

And here is the error for the web forms app
http://pastebin.com/LVuUy9Yg

Is there any way to start from fresh? I read on a related question, that a guy suggested to reinstall windows, but that isn't a viable option at all.

**EDIT:** Apparently when i was re-referencing to a new MySql dll file, it was a wrong version of it, so after installing a new one (a second time), and moving it into the bin, and referencing to it, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does the shortcut in the Start Menu set the working directory
   correctly? (I suspect that this is the most likely answer)
2. Is there a different/incorrect version of MySql.Data.dll installed
   in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)? I've seen this give similar
   error messages before.
3. Set 'Copy To Local' the Mysql.Data.dll reference from properties.
4. If MySql.Data is a mixed mode (native and managed code) 32 bit DLL.
       And you executable specifies "Any CPU". On a 64 bit machine with 64
       bit .NET this will fail with error message you got. A solution is to
       specify "x86" as target for the executable.

Comment: Sorry, but im rather new to messing around with the MySql connector, how do i check the first option you gave ?
Do you mean like checking for this: http://imgur.com/WDFuaxT ?

Comment: if you have install the connector directly from mysql website then appear on start menu.

Comment: Should i try to delete all the MySql folders+files in my GAC and then reinstall it?